# strace reports incorrect relative path?

Tags: linux, strace

I am using `strace` to report `open` and `chdir` system calls, and a fragment of its output is:

```
6791  chdir("//etc")                    = 0
6791  open("etc/fstab", O_RDONLY)       = 3
```

This doesn't make sense.  First we descend into the `/etc` directory, then the same process tries to open relative file `etc/fstab` from there.  The call succeeds, but there is no such file `/etc/etc/fstab`.  There is only the file `/etc/fstab`.

Why does strace report `etc/fstab` and not `/etc/fstab` as it should?

Answer (score 0):

Well...  apparently POSIX allows such a thing as a leading double slash in path names.  It means, not the root directory as one would think, but is implementation-dependent.  I guess in this case `//etc` is really the same as `/`.  I know this is crazy, but this is the only thing I can come up with.